# Map struct as a type (which can be nullable)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a `struct` which wraps `decimal` so I can use EditorTemplates, have type-safety, expand in future to add `Currency`, etc, etc:

```
public struct Price
{
    private readonly decimal value;

    public Price(decimal value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Price(decimal value)
    {
        return new Price(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator decimal(Price price)
    {
        return price.value;
    }
}
```

This is then used in many types which are mapped using Fluent NHibernate, for example:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Price SomePrice { get; set; }
    public virtual Price? NullablePrice { get; set; }
}
```

How can I tell FNH that when I do

```
public SomeEntityMap()
{
    this.Id(x => x.Id);
    this.Map(x => x.SomePrice);
    this.Map(x => x.NullablePrice);
}
```

that this should be just treated as a `decimal` and `Nullable<decimal>` respectively?

Preferably this would be without having to edit every mapping, as such I would prefer not to use a `IUserType` as this requires (I think) putting everywhere

```
this.Map(x => x.SomePrice).CustomType<PriceType>();
this.Map(x => x.NullablePrice).CustomType<NullablePriceType>();
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: So, mapped would be `protected virtual decimal DecimalValue {get; set;}` and the public property would be `public Price Price { get .... ` consuming the decimal value... is it a bit more clear?

Comment: @RadimKöhler Thanks, that is more clear, however a massive ache in the lower regions as there's so many of these throughout the project.

Comment: What do you mean with "should be treated as a decimal", can you give an example? In your mapping, is x.SomePrice a decimal or the Price struct?

If you want the behavior of a decimal then implement the mathematical operators on the struct? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s53ehcz3.aspx

Comment: @Cybrosys Question updated with example :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is achievable through [Components](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping) in a way similar to the [Following code extract](https://github.com/cbilson/QueryExamples/blob/master/QueryExamples/ReallyReallyComplicatedExample/Price.cs):

```
 Component(x => x.Price, m =>
{
m.Map(money => money.Amount, "Price_Amount");
m.Map(money => money.CurrencyCode, "Price_CurrencyCode");
});
```

Components are perfect method of mapping normalized data into a reusable entity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would this work when it is `Nullable<Price>` too?

Comment: Yes it should.Make sure the database field it maps to is null-able as well.